# How to mangle toplevel variable names using Uglify2 cli

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, uglifyjs

For reasons which escape me, uglifyjs does not appear to be [mangling top-level names](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#mangler-options).  What am I doing wrong?

A simple testugly.js looks like this:

```js
var testThing={};
testThing.something = 1;
testThing.myfunction = function(alpha,beta,c) {
    var dino = 5;
    if (alpha > 2) {
        dino = 6
    }
    return dino + beta * c 
}
```

Simple enough.  If I run it through uglify without trying to mangle top-level variables, things go as expected:

```sh
$ uglifyjs --version
uglify-js 2.4.0

$ uglifyjs testugly.js --mangle -c
var testThing={},testThing.something=1,testThing.myfunction=function(t,n,i){var e=5;return t>2&&(e=6),e+n*i};
```

Now, I'd like to mangle the top-level variables as well,so I add `toplevel=true`.

```sh
$ uglifyjs testugly.js --mangle toplevel=true -c
var testThing={},testThing.something=1,testThing.myfunction=function(t,n,i){var e=5;return t>2&&(e=6),e+n*i};
```

Or maybe I got that wrong, let's try the old `-mt` too.

```sh
$ uglifyjs testugly.js -mt -c
var testThing={},testThing.something=1,testThing.myfunction=function(t,n,i){var e=5;return t>2&&(e=6),e+n*i};
```

What gives?  Shouldn't `testThing` be 'a' or something?

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing your code in a function (-e):

```
$ uglifyjs testugly.js -e -mt -c
!function(){var n={};n.something=1,n.myfunction=function(n,t,i){var o=5;return n>2&&(o=6),o+t*i}}();
```

(version 2.4.3 here)